# how to make smartparens insert "` and "' instead of ``'' in latex-modes

Tags: latex, auctex, smartparens

Smartparens is quite useful, but I just do not understand its documentation.

**How do I make smartparens insert "` and "' instead of `` and '' when pressing " in latex-mode?**

**Remark** (because formating this question is somewhat difficult)
 Smartparens inserts :

```
``''
```

on `"`, but I need:

```
"`"'
```

*Note*: I do use `(require 'smartparens-config)` to initially set up smartparens stuff. This loads `smartparens-latex.el` and this sets up the ``'' pair. I'm not able to change the behavior to insert those pairs, which I need. Neither by editing `smartparens-latex.el` nor by commands in my `init.el`.
Also note: I'm using auctex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle the following lisp code should work in your initialization file.
The action `:rem` for `sp-local-pair` removes ``` ``'' ``` from the list of pairs
and thereafter we add `` "`"' `` . Furthermore we remove `TeX-insert-quote` from `LaTeX-mode-map`.

```el
(eval-after-load "smartparens-latex"
  '(sp-with-modes '(
              tex-mode
              plain-tex-mode
              latex-mode
              LaTeX-mode
              )
          (sp-local-pair "``" nil :actions :rem)
          (sp-local-pair "\"`" "\"'" :trigger "\"" :actions '(insert wrap)
                 :unless '(sp-latex-point-after-backslash))))

(eval-after-load "latex" '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map "\"" nil))
```

Note, that removing and adding of pairs to major modes is described there: https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Pair-management.

Since there seems to be a bug (see below), insertion with above code is not working. Therefore you could use following workaround:

```el
(eval-after-load "smartparens-latex"
    '(sp-with-modes '(tex-mode plain-tex-mode latex-mode LaTeX-mode)
         (sp-local-pair "``" nil :actions :rem)
         (sp-local-pair "\"" nil :actions nil)
         (sp-local-pair "\"`" "\"'" :trigger "\"" :actions '(insert wrap) 
                :unless '(sp-latex-point-after-backslash))))

(eval-after-load "latex" '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map "\"" nil))
```

This additional disables the global `" "` pair for latex modes.

---

A side-note on testing:

As of 2017-07-09 (melpa-version 20170708.1326), https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/ seems to be broken.

Already the unmodified version of `smartparen` shows strange behavior.
If I press <kbd>"</kbd> in the middle between `Testing` and `quotes` of the following LaTeX text

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
Testing  quotes
\end{document}
```

I get the following strange auto-insertion:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
Testing'' ` quotes
\end{document}
```

One can follow the execution of `sp-insert-pair`.
The trigger character `"` is deleted. The open part of the pair is decomposed into its prefix `"` and its last character `` ` ``.
The last character is inserted. Then it skips backward one thing. Thereby, the thing is whatever `sp-get-thing` returns (here it is just space).
There it inserts the closing part `''`.

Corresponding bug-report on the development page of `smartparens`: https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/issues/772.

If I use the above modification I get

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
Testing"' ` quotes
\end{document}
```

The double-quote of the closing part indicates that the pair is actually right.
But, we get the strange behavior as we get it for the unmodified version of `smartparens`.

Comment: Big thanks, with your help I got a better understanding of smartparens and I could find a workaround. Please review/edit/change my workaround information in your answer. Then I think your answer solves the problem.

Comment: @jue I removed my previous comment since it was not true. In my test of your fix I had `:actions nil` replaced by `:actions :rem`. With your version (`:actions nil`) it seems to work with the newest version of smartparens. I also tested the melpa-stable version (that is: 1.10.1). That worked without workaround.

Comment: @jue Finally I better understand your workaround. The case of `:actions nil` is not explicitly described in the documentation but one just has to accept it as one valid action list meaning that no actions are taken. The difference between `:actions :rem` and `:actions nil` is that `:actions :rem` removes the pair from the considered action list while `:actions nil` overrides the actions of the pair in the global list. Now I gained quite a bit insight into a minor-mode which I never use;-)).